# renew section command with tabular sections

Tags: macros, sectioning

I want to renew the section command so each section will follow by a fully two columns tabular.
it seems that it should be like:

```
\renewcommand{\section}[1]
{ 
\hfill\newline {#1}:\newline 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
}
```

the problem is `\end{tabular}` which I don't know where should I put it without need of something like *endsection*.

any idea?

Comment: This seems like a very odd thing to do.  What effect are you trying to achieve?  Maybe there's another way to do what you want.

Comment: I need all the sections to have two columns! that's all.

Comment: So what you want is a two column document, but with section headings that span both columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want two columns in your document you should use the `twocolumn` class option. If you only want two-column style in your section (which is kind of funny) it would be better to use the `multicol` package and its `{multicols}{<number>}` environment instead of `tabular`. I would then still avoid redefining `\section` and simply adding this environments by hand.