# Undefined control squence \Hy@writebookmark upon patching section command in beamer

Tags: beamer, etoolbox

I attempted to provide a solution to [Renew section command to wrap whole section in an environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27902/renew-section-command-to-wrap-whole-section-in-an-environment) and thought the best way was to use `etoolbox` to patch the `\section` command.  But this leads to:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 ...metitle {Text 1}\let \Hy@writebookmark \org
                                                  @writebookmark {}
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\documentclass{beamer}

\newif\ifInSection%
\global\InSectionfalse%
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\beamer@section{\ifInSection\end{frame}\fi\global\InSectiontrue}{}{}%
\apptocmd\beamer@section{\begin{frame}[fragile]{#1}}{}{}%
\makeatother

%\AtEndDocument{\end{frame}}% Needed to end the frame at \end{document}

\begin{document}
\section{Text 1}% Do a begin{frame} at end of this macro
Some text (1).
%\end{frame}% Start of next \section will do this

\section{Text 2}% Will end previous frame
Some text (2).
\end{frame}% Delete once \AtEndDocument above works
\end{document}
```

The `\pretocmd` is used to end the previous `frame` upon the start of a new `\section`, if a previous section was started.  The `\apptocmd` is used to start the `frame` at the end of the `\section`.

I am not very familiar with `beamer` so not sure if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: I think `beamer` needs to see `\end{frame}` in input, because it reads frame contents as an argument. Thus it will be hard to implement your idea.

Comment: Andrey is right.  Beamer looks for the `\end{frame}` explicitly.  (Actually, it looks for `\end something` but that still doesn't help you.)  What you'd have to do is slurp up everything between the `\section`s and put it in a frame.  The problem is that you don't know if your section will end with a `\section` or a `\end{document}` so you have to be careful how things are set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beamer's frame-gathering routine works by slurping in stuff up to the next `\end`, at which it tests the next "thing" to see if it is `{frame}` or not (there's also some testing for nesting).  Therefore at the time that the `\begin{frame}` is started, the `\end{frame}` needs to be in the token stream for it to find.  The TeX processor won't expand stuff to find it.

Because it looks for the `\end` it *might* be possible to hook in to the macro so that there was a test for `\end{document}` which added in the required `\end{frame}`, but it would require rewriting the macro as a whole to get it to work with the `\section` command.  There is no reason why `\section` *can't* appear inside a frame.  And once the `\section` command is read, beamer has already decided what is and isn't a frame so it's too late to try to persuade it otherwise.  The only way to make it reconsider is to `allowframebreaks` and have `\section` expand to add a `\newpage`.  But this would involve TeX slurping in the **whole** document in one go, which is probably Not a Good Idea.